# Why does my program return an error stating the file doesn't exist when it does?

Tags: go

I'm writing the basics of a custom scheduling tool, which will read a config file for "jobs" and add them to the schedule to run the periodically. It's very basic for now, like a proof of concept before refactoring and some additional more advanced features.

When I try to run this program, it reports that the script is not found. The script "test1.sh" does exist in the path where I'm trying to run it from, and it has execute permissions.

I'm getting the following error, but can't explain it or work it out as the script does exist at the path I'm running it:

```sh
-> ./scheduler-example
2021/08/16 12:48:54 fork/exec /Users/me/scheduler-example/scripts/test1.sh: no such file or directory
```

The scheduler code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "path/filepath"
    "time"

    "github.com/go-co-op/gocron"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
)

type Config struct {
    GlobalLog string `yaml:"GlobalLog"`
    Jobs      []Job  `yaml:"Jobs"`
}

type Job struct {
    Name      string `yaml:"Name"`
    Command   string `yaml:"Command"`
    Frequency string `yaml:"Frequency"`
    Tag       string `yaml:"Tag,omitempty"`
    Log       string `yaml:"Log,omitempty"`
}

const ROOT string = "/Users/me/scheduler-example"

func main() {
    // STEP1: Parse the config file
    configFile := filepath.Join(ROOT, "config", "scheduler-example.yaml")
    f, err := os.Open(configFile)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    configData, err := io.ReadAll(f)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    c := Config{}
    err = yaml.Unmarshal(configData, &c)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    // STEP2: Validate the config
    if c.GlobalLog == "" {
        log.Fatalln("Global log not defined")
    }
    if c.Jobs == nil {
        log.Fatalln("No jobs defined")
    }
    for _, j := range c.Jobs {
        if j.Name == "" {
            log.Fatalln("Job name not defined")
        }
        if j.Command == "" {
            log.Fatalln("Job command not defined")
        }
        if j.Frequency == "" {
            log.Fatalln("Job frequency not defined")
        }
    }

    // STEP3: Create the scheduler and add jobs
    s := gocron.NewScheduler(time.UTC)

    for _, j := range c.Jobs {
        script := filepath.Join(ROOT, "scripts", j.Command)
        cmd := exec.Command(script)
        cmdLog := filepath.Join(ROOT, "logs", j.Log)
        l, err := os.OpenFile(cmdLog, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }
        cmd.Stdout = l
        cmd.Stderr = l
        freq := j.Frequency
        tag := j.Tag
        s.Every(freq).Tag(tag).Do(func() {
            err = cmd.Run()
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalln(err)
            }
        })
    }

    // STEP4: Run the scheduler
    s.StartBlocking()
}
```

Config file:

```yaml
GlobalLog: /tmp/scheduler-example.log
Jobs:
  - Name: test1
    Command: test1.sh
    Frequency: 5s
    Tag: test1
    Log: test1.log
  - Name: test2
    Command: test2.sh
    Frequency: 5s
    Tag: test2
    Log: test2.log
```

Directory structure:

```sh
-> tree .
.
├── config
│   └── scheduler-example.yaml
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── logs
│   ├── test1.log
│   └── test2.log
├── scheduler-example.go
└── scripts
    ├── test1.sh
    └── test2.sh

3 directories, 8 files
```

The test1.sh script:

```sh
#!/bin/env bash

for i in {1..100}; do
    echo i
    sleep 10
done
```

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: It already has execute perms

Comment: try running "cat /Users/me/scheduler-example/scripts/test1.sh" in terminal and see if the file is getting printed or not..if it is then try updating your command as the one above need's some modification to work exec.Command(""sh", "-c", "/Users/me/scheduler-example/scripts/test1.sh"")

Comment: It does print, the file does exist with execute perms. What do you mean by add "sh" and "-c" - what's the issue with my command and what does that do? Can you explain further?

Comment: exec.Command -> is used to execute a named program (with some arguments) so when your trying to execute a script you have to add /bin/sh or /bin/bash (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25834277/executing-a-bash-script-from-golang) "sh", "-c" is an easy to use way to execute anything we are telling golang to execute sh with the argument(-c) "and your command" https://linux.die.net/man/1/sh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to Go documents

> Package exec runs external commands. It wraps os.StartProcess to make
> it easier to remap stdin and stdout, connect I/O with pipes, and do
> other adjustments.

It starts an isolated OS process. what you need is a terminal session or a direct bash call.

In Linux when you call `./script.sh` it actually means `/bin/sh  script.sh`. `./script.sh` works because the terminal (or CMD for .bat files on windows) treats the file as pure bash commands, line by line. so to run user-defined bash files we may use

```
cmd := exec.Command("/bin/sh",script)
```

or

```
cmd := exec.Command("bash",script)
```

**UPDATE**:
if this approach worked for you, read [torek's answare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68814607/8227389) to learn why exactly this works.

Actually what I said about "./script.py beeing bash ./script.sh is" is not quiet right

Answer (score 3):

Here's a minor technical correction to [OZahed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68803556/1256452), not really relevant to the Go language, but useful to know if you are writing code on Linux and Unix systems.

> In Linux when you call `./script.sh` it actually means `/bin/sh script.sh`.

This is not *quite* right.

On a Unix-like system, when you're sitting at a terminal prompt (`$` or `>` or `%` or whatever you have your prompt set to—lots of people use magic prompt-setters so that they get their current working directory plus perhaps some Git repository information or other useful items), you'll enter a command as:

```
$ cmd arg1 arg2
```

for instance.  The *shell* you are using—`/bin/sh`, `/bin/bash`, `/usr/local/bin/bash`, `dash`, `tcsh`, `fish`, etc.—is responsible for breaking up the entered line(s) and attempting to run one or more processes.  In general, they'll break this into <kbd>cmd</kbd>, <kbd>arg1</kbd>, and so on.  If some of these words contain shell *metacharacters* (`*`, `$`, and so on), they will do their own special actions with those metacharacters.  These can get quite complicated, but they are all up to that particular shell: the syntax used in `bash` differs from that in `tcsh`, for instance, in a number of important ways.

In any case, once this shell has gotten past the point of splitting up arguments and getting things ready to invoke the same `execve` system call that `exec.Cmd` will use in Go, the shell generally *does* invoke `execve`, often after using a `$path` or `$PATH` variable to search for the first or best executable to `execve` (again in a shell-dependent manner).  This system call:

- requires that the supplied path name a file;
- requires that the named file be *marked* with execute *permissions*; and
- requires that the named file contain data that the *OS itself considers executable*.

If any of these three tests fail, the `execve` system call itself will fail.

It's at this point that Go's `exec.Cmd` and the shells tend to diverge rather sharply.  If the file exists and is marked executable, but `execve` fails, a *shell* will usually do one or both of the following:

- open and read (perhaps just part of) of the file to try to guess *which shell, if any, might run this file*, then
- run that shell, or some default shell, *on* that file.

It's that last step that results in `/bin/sh ./script.sh`, for instance.  If the script appears to be a `/bin/sh` script, your shell—even if it's `tcsh`—should use `/bin/sh ./script`.  If the script appears to be a `bash` script, your shell should locate the `bash` program and run that program with `./script.sh` as an argument.

#### The key trick to know about executable scripts: `#!`

Note that the above requires that we get an error from the OS-level `execve` system call.  We can *avoid this error*, on any modern Unix system, by *starting our script with a special line*.  This special line takes the form of two characters, `#` and `!`, followed by optional white space, followed by the path name of an *interpreter* program, followed by more optional white space and—depending on the particular OS—one or more arguments.

That is, if we write our shell script as:

```
#! /bin/sh
echo this was run by /bin/sh
```

and make it executable, the `execve` system call, applied to this script, acts as if it were an `execve` system call invoking `/bin/sh` followed by the path name of this script.  So if the path name we used was `./script`, we get the *effect* of running `/bin/sh ./script`.

The `/bin/sh` part *came out of the script*, so we get to control the exact path of the interpreter.  If we write an awk script, for instance, and if the `awk` interpreter is in `/usr/bin/awk`, then:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk
```

is the correct first line.

Amusingly, this gives us the ability to write a self-removing script:

```
#! /bin/rm
```

When run, this script removes itself.  (The remainder of the file, if any, is irrelevant: the `/bin/rm` command simply removes the named file.)  Using `/bin/mv` as the interpreter produces a self-renaming script.

A common trick these days, due to programs like `python` being in `/usr/bin` on some systems and `/usr/local/bin` on others, is to use the POSIX `env` command to locate the binary for the interpreter:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
```

invokes `/usr/bin/env python ./script.py`.  The `env` command uses `$PATH` to locate the `python` command and then calls `execl` (a C library wrapper for the `execve` system call) with `/usr/local/bin/python ./script.py` or whatever is appropriate.  If a system has both python2 and python3 installed, with `python2` and `python3` invoking the specific variant, `#! /usr/bin/env python3` ensures that we find a python3 interpreter, rather than a python2 interpreter.

Had you written your script with the appropriate `#!` line, you would never have asked the question that led to these answers. :-)

Comment: It was really informative, and it convinced me to read more about Linux. Thank you so much